# React-Native-Snap-Carousel component is not showing properly

Tags: react-native, carousel, native-base

I am using [react-native-snap-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel) NPM package with [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/) in a react-native app. I am able to load the page successfully but the carousel is not showing up the children components as expected. Cards in Carousel are rendering very small (very small height, not visible clearly)

If I use the card component in `<ListItem>` component of NativeBase, the cards come up perfectly fine, but when use the same card component under carousel component, cards are messed up. Most probably it something related to styles of carousel children component.

This is how carousel looks like on Android (not tested on iOS):
[image]

Below is the code.

**BusinessCarousel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Text, View } from 'native-base';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import BusinessCard from './card';

export class BusinessCarousel extends Component {
  _renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return <BusinessCard business={item} />;
  }

  render() {
    const businesses = [
      {
        name: 'business 1',
        details:
          'Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details ',
        address: {
          fullAddress: 'some address'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'business 2',
        details:
          'Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details ',
        address: {
          fullAddress: 'some address'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'business 3',
        details:
          'Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details Business 1 details ',
        address: {
          fullAddress: 'some address'
        }
      }
    ];

    return (
        <Carousel
          ref={c => {
            this._carousel = c;
          }}
          data={businesses}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          sliderWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
          itemWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8}
          containerCustomStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
          contentContainerCustomStyle={{ overflow: 'visible' }}
        />
    );
  }
}
```

**BusinessCard (card.js)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Card,
  CardItem,
  Left,
  Right,
  Thumbnail,
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Body,
  Icon
} from 'native-base';

export default class BusinessCard extends Component {
  _getLogoURL() {
    const { business } = this.props;
    if (business.logo && business.logo.url) return { uri: business.logo.url };
    return require('../../public/no-image-available.png');
  }

  render() {
    const { business } = this.props;
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardItem>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={this._getLogoURL()} />
            <Body>
              <Text>{business.name}</Text>
              <Text note numberOfLines={1}>
                {(business.address && business.address.fullAddress) || ''}
              </Text>
            </Body>
          </Left>
          <Right>
            <Icon name="create" />
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <Text>{business.details}</Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap Card component with Container component from NativeBase?

Comment: No. You can see in above code, `card.js` is returning `<Card>` as top level component.

Comment: I thought maybe you tried before. Then can you try it?

Comment: Have you tried using a pure View as carousel element? I guess there's some style given to native base component which is causing this behavior. Maybe a 'flex: 1'

Comment: I also had similar problem check this : [https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/134](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/134)
this might help you

Comment: @bennygenel I tried wrapping Card component under Container component, but that did not help. I tried many other options, but nothing is helping.

Comment: @soutot what you mean by pure View component ? Yeah, sure its a styling issue as when I debugged the app in ReactNativeDebugger I could see the cards somehow after manipulating styles of carousel children deep down. Can you try my above code and give some suggestions. Thanks for help.

Comment: @AdarshSreeram I went through the link shared by you. You issue was more of related to image source path. Mine is somewhat related to styling as I am using NativeBase component in Snap Carousel so looks like somewhere the styles are getting overridden, but not sure where.

Comment: @GauravDhiman I meant to use <View> (from React Native) instead of <Card> and <CardItem> in your BusinessCard component. If that fixes the issue, maybe you can try looking in NativeBase Card and/or CardItem component to understand the styles they have that might conflict with your carousel. I'm pretty sure that's something related to flex: 1